# Migrating MOSS 2007 to sharepoint 2010 giving the error “Invalid Object Name sites”

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am migrating sharepoint 2007 publishing site to sharepoint 2010. These are the steps I have followed

1. Backup the content database from the SP2007 machine.
2. Restore that database in sql server 2008 (SP2010 machine).
3. Create a new web application in SP2010 and create a site collection type of publishing template.
4. I have run the following stsadm command for adding the content database to the web application
   stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://testsite -databasename WSS_Content_test

But I am getting the **Invalid object name sites** error. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow [correct procedures](http://www.social-point.com/migrating-a-sharepoint-2007-blog-to-2010-part-1)? Did you do a pre-upgrade check?